# Debugger for google appengine python

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine

I am developing for appengine python on windows 7. I am looking for a set up that will allow me to debug my python scripts. I would prefer a GUI based defugger as opposed to command line one. Something like eclipse provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aptana is an Eclipse modification, you can use it for several languages.

Aptana ( http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2/download) + pydev (aptana/myaptana/plugins/Aptana Pydev/Get It).

And Netbeans is Able to debug python too... http://netbeans.org , but a little bit complicated to download the nbm...

Comment: +1: I use Aptana and pydev on Windows 7 - it includes direct support for google app engine, and the debugging works well.

Answer (score 2):

If non-free (as beer) is a option, WingIDE is a very powerful Python IDE, especially [It's new version 4 (still in beta)](http://www.wingware.com/wingide/beta) puts focus on Django Debug support.
It's a GUI based Debugger as you want, and has a how-to for "[Using Wing IDE with the Google App Engine](http://www.wingware.com/doc/howtos/google-app-engine)"

Comment: I can't agree strongly enough with this option. I use Wing IDE for all ofb my AppEngine development, and it is easily the best money that i ever spent on a software tool. $35 for the personal version is a fantastic bargain.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/